# Encode unescaped JSON in Yii 1.x

Tags: php, json, yii, escaping, encode

I need to generate JSON from PHP array, whitout escaping `/` characters (mostly un URLs).

In pure PHP I can do just `json_encode($results, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` (in PHP 5.4.0+).

Is there any way, I can achieve the same using `CJSON::encode();` or any other Yii 1.x class?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don;t want to use json_encode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the code of [CJSON](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/helpers/CJSON.php#L323), you see that it uses standard php if available for decode/encode functions. Unfortunately it's not up to speed yet with 5.4 as Yii 1.x has a requirement of PHP 5.1.

I suggest you add the extra functionality by extending CJON yourself, something like this :

```
class MyJSON extends CJSON {
    public static function encode($var, $options = null, $depth = null)
    {
        if (function_exists('json_encode') && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') >= 0) {
            return json_encode($var, $options, $depth);
        } elseif (function_exists('json_encode') && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
            return json_encode($var, $options);
        } else {
            return parent::encode($var);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is, for sure, more professional way of doing so, but when we look at KISS, I think, this is an overkill and I think, I'll remain with just `json_encode()`! :]